# Could not install the app into iPhone because of Mach-O linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios-frameworks

I'm trying to install an app into iPhone and i'm getting a Mach-O-linker error as one of the framework missing.
Project runs successfully in simulator but not on device even after adding the missing framework.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vinayakgh/Desktop/Splunk'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FMint'
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And there is no problem WRT to AFNetworking but with another framework(SpluntMint).

Can anyone help me out in solving this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Location has changed either your project's or the libraries you used.

Comment: try cleaning the project and make sure all resources exists at the specified path

Comment: First 3 are just warnings. its the 4th line which shows a linker error. Please post a detailed version of this error.

Comment: I think you should check for Framework search path or library search path in Build settings under Project settings

Comment: Yes i had checked for the location and added them once again and yes all the resources exists

Comment: @manish_kumar:  Hey thank you, yes thats where lies the problem i guess and i have to change the search paths for frameworks in build settings ..need to check now

Answer (score 0):

Go to Target Then Build Phase Then Find Link Binary with library and you will get that Which File or Framework is Misplaced or Remove...

Then Delete that from then and add it again manually.

This is one of temporary Solution that worked for me.

[image: Red colour file are Missing file.But here No file is missing.]

Comment: Thank you, I agree with your response ..at this case this is not the problem, FYI i just found out that we need to change the search path for frameworks under BuildSettings to the framework we just referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for Framework Search path or Library Search paths in Build settings under Project settings. See if the path specified there are correct or not.